# Why would energy conservation be violated during interference if a wave function represented multiple photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, interference

the below paragraph is from Paul Dirac's 'The principles of quantum mechanics'. He argues that representing multiple photons' probability distribution via a single wavefunction leads to energy conservation violation. I don't quite get the argument since in an interferometer there are at least 2 ports (like Mach-Zhender interferometer) and so energy shouldn't be violated as it would appear somewhere else? Can someone break down his argument into simpler terms for me and explain? Thanks a bunch.
[image]

Comment: All photons emitted and hitting the screen have the same frequency/energy. So two photons disappearing or else fusing into four photons violates energy conservation. In practice, for weak beams, you get sporadic photons hitting a screen, whose probabilities are traced out by a large number of independent photons. Can you explain how you get around Dirac's argument?

Comment: Substitute photons for the electrons in the [Hitachi double slit demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FDR4ZuLnQo).

Comment: @CosmasZachos but how can we even claim that two photons have to fuse when we consider a common wave function? What I mean to say is: if each path of interferometer is a wavefunction, then these two interfere and the probabilities of finding photons at certain position gets adjusted by sending more photons to peaks in the interference pattern and less photons to interference pattern.

Comment: Who does the numerical adjustment in M-Z according to path differences?  If you don’t have a model, there is nothing to explain.

Comment: I am also curious to understand what is meant with "they would have to produce four photons": what kind of observation is meant with this statement or how does one come to such a conclusion?

Comment: I think what Dirac means is that to force energy conservation to hold at every locality and every time instant simultaneously one cannot consider the wave function  to represent a statistical ensemble of photons, instead it must describe a *single* photon. Otherwise, energy conservation can only be satisfied on the average but not in detail.

Comment: My sense is Dirac is not considering, e.g., two photon states (wavefunctions). He is contrasting the incoherent ensemble of two photons, and demonstrating that this ensemble is not represented by a wavefunction, but by two separate wavefunctions, each for each photon, interfering only with itself. He is shooting down a horse dead for about a century, now: interpretation of the square of the wavefunction as multiplicity of photons!

Comment: Each photon in the ensemble independently interferes with the slits and populates a spot on the screens, in a distribution revealed by multiple replication, as in the Hitachi experiment.

Comment: @hyportnex if you understand it, could you explain how making a wavefunction represent a statistical ensemble leads to this. Here’s how I am picturing the situation: if the wavefunction represents statistical ensemble, then we get what we expect in photon distribution. Please explain

Comment: @CosmasZachos sorry for keep asking but, could you explain very simply why the two photons ensemble being represented by a single wavefunction cause problems? If the wavefunction’s amplitude increases at some point due to constructive interf. then simply probabilities are affected. We don’t know what’s going on with the 2 photons right?

Comment: My admittedly *naïve* interpretation of Dirac is that if *two* photons can destructively interfere, ie.,  annihilate, each other at one point at one instant then there and then we just failed energy conservation. But if we consider this interference as a statistical one on the average then energy is conserved on the *average* that is averaged over all photons as that ensemble is being described by the wave function. If instead we consider a photon as a *wave* all by itself then interference is not a problem for local conservation, instead the problem is *imagining* it how that could happen.

Comment: But Dirac did not say that a wavefunction which can interfere with itself causes problems: you did. Dirac is considering an incoherent ensemble not representable by a multiparticle wavefunction, the older, clumsy, attempts in the "old quantum theory" of the early twenties. This is what his book explains. You aim to stretch it to something else, without explaining how!

Comment: Cosmas Zachos and hyportnex seem to me to have answered the question convincingly: two photons that annihilate each other violate energy conservation (energy disappears) and so do two photons that produce two new photons (energy reappears), as needed in order to produce an interference pattern that conserves energy. I suggest that Cosmas Zachos or hyportnex summarize this into a concise reply.

Answer (score 0):

In high school in the double slit we are taught that 2 photons "interfere" and the interpretation is that they cancel each other .... this is very convenient and mathematically correct but it is entirely FALSE.

Firstly it is a violation of conservation of energy .... and NO, the energy can NOT go somewhere else .... that would be magic!

As Dirac and Feynman stated each photon is "interfering" with itself, which can be more clearly stated as ..."Each photon is determining its own path!".  So how can a photon which is just created know where to go ???, it seems like an impossibility and IT IS an impossibility. So what's going on?

The EM field is very dynamic and it is the EM field that guides the photon or electron in the double slit or in any optical experiment. The EM field does not ignore the excited electron in the excited atom, the EM field is interacting with the excited electron/atom long before any real photon is released.  These interactions are mediated but what are called virtual photons ....  virtual photons are just a concept to explain EM forces like electrostatics, realize that the forces are real.

IT is most likely that the virtual forces/waves are the ones that cancel at the dark points ... and the Feynman path integral is a great way to calculate the probability pattern.  Thus if we consider the EM field in its entirety there's no mystery.

Comment: I would edit the answer to remove the all caps except for EM.

Comment: @Themis. I get your point .... but I'm feeling the need for emphasis.  If Meet responds or a seconder I'll edit it.